# How do you find a list of questions with an open bounty?

Tags: support, questions, bounty

Is there such a feature on SO? I was just curiously browsing the list of questions and was surprised that I couldn't find a list of questions with open bounties. To put it another way: How do you find the questions which have open bounties?

Please forgive me if I've missed something obvious.

Comment: They are called "featured." There is a tab for them on the home page.

Comment: The Featured Tab is mentioned in the Help Center topic [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the "featured" tab. This tab can be filtered like the main question list based on tags or just globally.